# Problem with the encoding of a web page

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get some information from a web... with the code above...

```
URL url = new URL(webpage);
URLConnection connection;
connection = url.openConnection();

BufferedReader in;
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1");
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

But I'm having a problem with the encoding when I'm reading it. The page is in spanish, and it has some simbols like "ñ" or "á". The header of the source code of the page says that it's in "iso-8859-1", and I've tried with "utf-8", but none of them works... when I try to set the text I'm reading from the URL to a TextView it just shows garbage in the simbols I've told....

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are creating the reader incorrectly

```
inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1");
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

The first statement is creating a Reader with the specified encoding, but the second one is ignoring the original Reader and creating a new one with the default encoding for your platform.  You probably need to do this:

```
inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1");
in = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
```

Comment: You can leave that "I think" and "probably" away :)

Comment: I think you are probably right :-)  But we don't know for sure that the quoted code is the actual code.